# How to keep staff and users in separate tables with another table that gives them a general accountID?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables, `staff` and `users`. Below are shortened versions of the tables.
**(* = PK, # = FK)**

```
staff { staffID*, username, ... }

users { userID*, username, ... }
```

I want to make it so that these tables have a table that links them together in a way that they are given an `accountID`.

I was thinking that this will be something along the lines of...

```
accounts { accountID*, accountType, localID# }
```

...where `localID` is either; the `staffID` if the account is from the `staff` table, or the `userID` if the account is from the `users` table. The `accountType` would be the used to tell which table the account is from and would have possible values of `staff` and `user`.

**First off** - is this possible to accomplish this way? Is this a good idea? Since both the `staff` and `users` tables have the field `username`, should I instead use `username` in the `accounts` table in place of `accountType` and `localID`? (*If there exists a record in the `staff` table with the `username` 'foo', then there cannot be a record in the `user` table with the `username` 'foo'*)

**Secondly** - If the tables above are the way that I should implement this, what constraint would I need to add to make it so `accountType` & `localID` are unique such that all the examples in *Figure 1* would be accepted, whereas the examples in *Figure 2* that are duplicate combinations of `accountType` and `localID` would not?

*Figure 1*

```
|-----------|-------------|---------| 
| accountID | accountType | localID |
|-----------|-------------|---------|
|     1     |      A      |    1    |
|     2     |      B      |    1    |
|     3     |      A      |    2    |
|     4     |      B      |    2    |
|-----------|-------------|---------|
```

*Figure 2*

```
|-----------|-------------|---------|
| accountID | accountType | localID |
|-----------|-------------|---------|
|     1     |      A      |    1    |
|     2     |      A      |    1    |
|     3     |      B      |    2    |
|     4     |      B      |    2    |
|-----------|-------------|---------|
```

**Reasoning** - I want these separate tables for staff and users to because I want role based access control, but I want it such that there are roles only a staff account can have & there are other roles that only a user account can have.

Thanks in advance for any help/guidance offered.

Comment: Why not put them all in one table, with a extra column 'role' so you can deside on that value if user has privileges for 'staff' actions

Comment: Previously I have had it how you have said and it works, but I want it so that it isn't ever possible for a `user` to take a `staff` role, without having a hard-coded select element with an if statement on the page where this choice would be made/changed.

Comment: Ok, that's fair. And putting them in one table with another table holding only id's of staff members is no option? So users are only staff if their ID is also in table2. I think you'll regret at some point that you have 2 tables with userdata.

Comment: Basically, there is a `companies` table in my database too. Each `user` belongs to a `company`, whereas `staff` obviously don't belong to a _customer_ `company`. If I do as you say and have all `accounts` in one table (regardless if `staff` or `user`) would I then need another two tables, called `companyAccounts` (this would act as a link between a `company` and a `user` & `staffAccounts` which only `accounts` that are deemed as `staff` are stored. I would then need to make it so that an `accountID` cannot appear in both `companyAccounts` and `staffAccounts` right?

Answer (score 0):

Add the accountId in staff and user table, that would accomplish what your looking for.

Comment: If I do that then how do I have an `auto_increment` primary key for `accountID` so that no staff and user can have the _same_ `accountID`? Would I make a new table that has just one field that's auto_increment and then I, (or just an int that I just update the record by +1 every time so there isn't a large number of records) which will store the `next` value for the `accountID`? Care to enlighten me as to why you think that this is the best way?

Comment: once an account is created you associate with the user or staff, you don't need a separate table nor worry about updating the record by 1,  Offcourse the best way is to create a role type table as suggested, but with current design have a nullable accountId column in both staff and user table and associate it when account is created.

Comment: Think I might just create a `roleType` field for my `roles` table to be honest, and have all `users` and `staff` in one table `accounts` that has a `roleID`, as the first comment on my question suggests. Maybe I have been overcomplicating this.